# How do I distort a camera ray to simulate a calibrated camera?

Tags: opencv, vision

What I have:

- a camera calibrated [by opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html) (I know all the k's, s's and tau's)
- a position and orientation (I know R and t)
- a point on the image plane (u, v)
- a distance along the ray passing through (u, v)

What I want:

- the 3D point at the given distance along the ray passing through (u, v), taking distortion into account

Is there something in opencv that does this or do I have to derive it myself?

Comment: You have `K`, and the true depth `Z`? For a given `(u,v)`, apply the reverse perspective transformation with `undistortPoints()`. It gives you `(x,y,1)`. The 3D coordinate is then `(x*Z, y*Z, Z)`.

Comment: @Catree I want to distort, though, not to undistort.

Comment: Th camera model goes like this: `(X,Y,Z)` in camera frame, then depth is "removed" with perspective projection `(x,y,1)`, then projection into the image plane `(u,v)`, then distortion is applied. Distortion is applied in the projection image. So either you are dealing with distortion in the image, and you can undistort your 2D coordinates or either you are distortion free.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c) of `projectPoints` function. Especially at the note at the end:

> By setting rvec=tvec=(0,0,0) or by setting cameraMatrix to a 3x3
>   identity matrix, or by passing zero distortion coefficients, you can
>   get various useful partial cases of the function. **This means that you
>   can compute the distorted coordinates for a sparse set of points** or
>   apply a perspective transformation (and also compute the derivatives)
>   in the ideal zero-distortion setup.

Comment: projectPoints returns 2D points on the image plane. I'm going in the other direction, from points on the image plane and distances to 3D points.